# Why Font Weight isn't changing with Tailwindcss font family?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have the needs to change my fonts to "Helvetica Neue" which is listed on tailwindcss font-sans properties. I managed to change the font, but when I tried to change the font weight, nothing seems to work.

I've tried to modify the fontWeight property on tailwind.config.js but even when I used the modified value nothing change. It seems like this problem also exist with other custom fontFamily. So far, fontWeight only works with default font by tailwindcss. Below are my tailwind.config.js code, I have not added anything to the index.css.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html",
  "./src/*.{jsx,js}",
    "./src/**/*.{jsx,js}"],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      'main-blue':'#0066B2',
      'secondary-blue':'#4B8EC2',
      'background':'#4B8EC2',
      'white': colors.white
    },
    fontFamily: {
      'sans': ['"Helvetica Neue"', 'Arial', 'sans-serif']
    },
    fontWeight: {
      'black': '95'
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

95 is not a valid font weight per CSS standards. Font weight starts at 100 (thin).

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight?retiredLocale=pl)

Comment: Oh yeah, it seems there's little change there its barely visible. Does it have anything to do with helvetica font itself?

Comment: Do you only have `Helvetica-Regular.ttf` in your fonts directory or the whole font package? (`Helvetica-Bold, Italic, SemiBold` etc.)? For different font weights you need to embed different font files.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using a valid value for `fontWeight`

The [Docs](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/font-weight) use the standard CSS values, 100-900.

Example:

```js
  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    theme: {
      fontWeight: {
       hairline: 100,
       'extra-light': 100,
       thin: 200,
        light: 300,
        normal: 400,
        medium: 500,
       semibold: 600,
        bold: 700,
       extrabold: 800,
       'extra-bold': 800,
        black: 900,
      }
    }
```

[Source](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/font-weight#font-weights)

Comment: Thanks. I noticed small change now, its barely visible. Just a question. Does this barely visible change have anything to do with the font itself? If I want a really bold font I have to use "Helvetica Neue Bold", aren't I?

Comment: Well a value of `900` will give you the boldest available font for a given font-family, and some fonts won't have the ability to be more bold, regardless of the font-weight (but that's fairly rare I believe). Very often though, increasing the [font size in the config](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size#customizing), even a small amount, will make the text render more boldly too. Don't forget to mark the question as accepted with the green tick if you found this helpful